# The use of the word "except" with "to" + a verb

Tags: infinitives, bare-infinitives

I read in one grammar book that after *except* we have to use a bare infinitive. For example:

> She had nothing to do except **spend** money.

But in this [dictionary](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/except) they provide an example with a verb and *to*. Here it goes:

> He wouldn’t talk about work, except **to say** that he was busy.

I am really confused. Does that mean that the author of the book is wrong or the dicionary is wrong.

Comment: Neither is wrong. It simply is just so complex to understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> He wouldn’t talk about work, except to say that he was busy.

In this example, "to" means "in order to". He would talk about work [in order] to say that he was busy, but not otherwise.

So here "to" is functioning as something closer to a full preposition rather than simply an infinitive-marking particle.